# Float in c++ smaller range than IEEE 754

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

I try to make the following division: `1/16777216`, what is equal to `5.96046448e-8`
but this:

```
printf("number: %f \n", 1.0f / 16777216.0f);
```

allways gives me `0.00000` instead of the answer I would expect.
I looked up the ranges, because I thought well, that might be a problem that float is simply to smal
to handle such a number, but [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Single_precision) states it to be `±1.18×10−38`.

Am I missing something and thats why the result not the expected one?

Comment: OP was clearly asking about C++. In both the title and the tags. Not sure why it was changed to C. `printf` is part of the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using fixed formatting (`%f`) you get a format with a decimal point and up to 6 digits. Since the value you used rounds to a value smaller than `0.000001` it seems reasonable to have `0.000000` printed. You can either use more digits (I *think* using `%.10f` but I'm not that good at `<stdio.h>` format specifiers) or you change the format to use either scientific notation (`%e`) or the "better" of both options (`%g`).

Comment: That solved it, thank you. I'll mark it as answer when I can (have to wait 7 minutes)

Comment: "rounds to a value smaller than `0.000000`": That can't be right!

Comment: @TonyK: yes, you are right: there should be a `1` at the end. I'll fix that small issue.

Comment: In particular, the format specification `% 15.8e` will display as many decimal digits as are needed to uniquely identify any IEEE-754 single-precision number, while the format specification `% 23.16e` will do the same for IEEE-754 double precision numbers. You may also want to look at the format specifier `%a` if you are interested in the exact binary representation of floating-point operands including non-numeric operands like NaNs.

Comment: @njuffa - `%1.8e` and `%1.16e` are sufficient for IEEE-754 round-trip conversion.

Comment: @Brett Hale: Sure. As [Goldberg's seminal paper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) states: "However, if nine decimal digits are used, then converting the decimal number to the closest binary number will recover the original floating-point number. [...] The same argument applied to double precision shows that 17 decimal digits are required to recover a double precision number." So any format specification satisfying those conditions will accomplish the goal, including the ones you and I listed. I didn't mean to imply otherwise, merely gave an example.